# Selecting using `database_name`.`viewname`.* syntax in MySQL throws "Unknown table 'database_name.viewname'"

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm having a strange issue with MySQL and database views.

I have a view defined like this:

```
CREATE VIEW circuits AS
(SELECT Id, Id AS Old_Id, Name FROM circuits_1)
UNION
(SELECT Id + 1000 AS Id, Id AS Old_Id, Name FROM circuits_2)
```

I have to join this view with a table that is in another database.

To do so, I usually prefix the table name with its database name, like `db_name`.`table_name`.

I've mapped this view using an ORM, specifying its prefix, and the resulting query is this one:

```
SELECT `webapp`.`circuits`.* FROM `webapp`.`circuits`
```

But this query returns this error:

```
#1051 - Unknown table 'webapp.circuits'
```

However, **I've tried to manually run the query and remove the `webapp`. prefix from the `SELECT` statement, and it works as expected, throwing no error at all**

```
SELECT `circuits`.* FROM `webapp`.`circuits`
```

Any idea why this happens?

Is it related to the way the view is defined?

## EDIT

Another strange thing:
Even if this query fails:

```
SELECT `webapp`.`circuits`.* FROM `webapp`.`circuits`
```

This doesn't:

```
SELECT `webapp`.`circuits`.Id FROM `webapp`.`circuits`
```

Comment: i have a feeling you have created the view in the wrong database?

Comment: @RaymondNijland `SELECT `circuits`.* FROM `webapp`.`circuits`` works, so no. ^^'

Comment: The prefix webapp means your database name . Check your view is inside this database.

Comment: Check his last comment @SumeshTG

Comment: Yes it is: [Screen](http://i68.tinypic.com/21rlzc.png)

Comment: Are using remote connection or localhost.

Comment: Remote connection. However, I've tried the same query also from phpmyadmin, that uses localhost. Same result.

Comment: Check is there any issue in user privilleges.

Comment: Yep, the orm is able to handle views. However, as I've said, I've tried to run the queries directly from phpmyadmin: same result.

Comment: @RaymondNijland the error message comes from MySQL, not from the ORM... From the ORM's point of view, there is no difference between a table and a view.

Comment: @SumeshTG I've tried to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` to the user, no changes

Comment: Isn't it possible that the ORM generated code was `webapp.circuits` not `webapp`.`circuits`? (the database and viewname were enclosed by backticks as opposed to database name enclosed by backticks and table name enclosed by backticks?

Comment: @RaymondNijland The ORM is ActiveRecord. However, I'm using it with other views with no problem, and I've tried the generated query directly on phpmyadmin.
@Shadow I've copy-pasted the generated query exactly as it was generated, so the ``` are in the right position

Comment: Sure, but it's also an ORM name: I mean, the Ruby on Rails Active Record. However, I don't think it could be the problem, as I just said, as I've tried that query in phpmyadmin and the error is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I was hesitant to answer, as i am not familiar enough with mysql to give a full answer. I did some testing on rextester.com though, and found the following:

If I `create` a `table test(id int)`, I can query it using its fully qualified object name:

```
SELECT rextester.test.* 
FROM rextester.test
```

Works, no problem.

If I `create` a `view so_test as (Select 1 id from dual)`

I cannot do the same:

```
SELECT rextester.so_test.* 
FROM rextester.so_test
```

Returns the same error you get.

I cannot conclude too much from this, as i don't know mysql well enough. However, it seems a general issue with views, not the way you created it.

Comment: Want happens if you create the view with `ALGORITME=MERGE` iám wondering now?

Comment: Wow, this is really strange. THe strangest thing is that I have another view in the same database, and it's not having this issue at all. Maybe it's a bug in mysql?

Comment: @RaymondNijland... I don't know what that option does or how it affects this issue. I'll leave it for someone else to do the test. I have to say, this does feel a bit like a bug.

Comment: "I don't know what that option does or how it affects this issue" `ALGORITME=MERGE` forces MySQL to rewrite (optimize) the query `SELECT rextester.test.* 
FROM rextester.test` into `Select 1 from dual` it's explained in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html  "I have to say, this does feel a bit like a bug" Yes it does.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Couldnt help myself, i did the test, same result.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Another strange thing: `SELECT `webapp`.`circuits`.Id FROM `webapp`.`circuits`` doesn't fail at all.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not seam to support `*` rewrite to the matching table columns with in the VIEW.

MySQL 5.6.39 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68f2d3/4

MySQL 5.7
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/taRV6FLAP6Mf8oMeuniZP3/2

MySQL 8.0.11
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/taRV6FLAP6Mf8oMeuniZP3/3

Comment: Yep, but check this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68f2d3/6

If you use * instead of Id, it fails

Comment: Yes it more seams the error pops up when using * to select the columns.

Comment: Yes it more seams the error pops up when using * to select the columns. it happens in all MySQL versions @ProGM time to trace it.

Comment: Ach, so it's some kind of bug, I think. I'll try to report it to the mysql bug tracker

Comment: "Ach, so it's some kind of bug" Maybe using `*` is unlogical because a view can acces multiple databases and or tables at the same time.. And maybe thats is one of the reasons why it's never implemented

Comment: It is considered bad practice to use `Select *` anyway.

Comment: @ProGM Just to close the issue in my mind, you do not use * with your other view (the one that works as expected)?

Comment: "It is considered bad practice to use Select * anyway." For performance a yes .. For usability a no @HoneyBadger

Comment: "Just to close the issue in my mind, you do not use * with your other view (the one that works as expected)?" The problem is a ORM (software) is generating the SQL @HoneyBadger

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, but the (potential) bug is a mysql one. If the other view in also queried by `Select *` (whether by ORM generated query or a manually written one) some more digging might be warranted.